# Something is opening Spam URL in my Browser, how do I find out what did this?

Tags: browser

Sometimes, when using my phone, suddenly my browser (Google Chrome) opens up and tries to open a Spam URL. This will occur again and again, until I restart the phone.

It does not seem to be related with the app I am using at that specific moment, and it keeps happening even if I kill all running apps.

Now I wonder: Is there a way to find out what is making my browser open this URL? Is this logged somewhere, or can this be logged somehow?

Android Version is 5.0.1, device is a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: Not sure if there is a simple way. Could you list the link for the apps which you were using whenever that spamm URL was suddenly launched into Chrome out of nowhere? My take is that instead of directly passing URL into Chrome, that fishy app would be using `android.intent.action.VIEW` and the system would launch the URL with whatever is set as default browser. Another thing to note here is that unless that app is running a background service or listens to a particular broadcast, it won't be able to do anything, let alone launch a URL *unless it is in foreground*. So, can you list those apps?

Comment: Can you also mention that URL?

Comment: Sorry, I know this question came first, but the linked duplicate has an answer proved useful (mine).

Answer (score -1):

If you use android studio, you can connect your phone and enable usb debugging, then simply filter the LOGCAT for "http://" and find your culprit.

Here's a URL on DDMS:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

[image]

Comment: Please provide a specific use case of your answer and show how the final result would look like. I've tried the approach with logcat. Doesn't seem to be helping out. I maybe doing something incorrectly so it would be nice if you sort things at your end.

Comment: Yeah, I'll make a quick app example tonight and filter with logcat...  I think your comment on the top question is correct too, it's likely using the common Intent.ACTION_VIEW